# iTunesConnect - iAP

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

My app was working correctly all the time. However, the company management forgot to pay for the iTunes paid apps account. They fixed that yesterday, now it is paid, the iAP is shown as "Approved" & the box "Cleared for Sale" is checked, but in the iOS AppStore I can't see these purchases. Also inside the app it doesn't seem to work. Do I need to refresh something?

Maybe I need to publish a new app version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it went out, that it needs about 48hours after they payment for the iAP to be available.